# Catalina wont let me install gulp or other apps using npm

Tags: macos, npm, macos-catalina

I have a fresh install of Mac OS Catalina and it wont let me install npm apps. I tried both sudo and non sudo.

```
npm install --global browser-sync
```

but got this error,

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync'] {
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/nicholasdixon/.npm/_logs/2019-12-14T07_09_23_421Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a UNIX issue from reinstalling the OS.

You can fix it by typing into your terminal:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

This worked for me, hope it will do the same for you.

Comment: Took a little while on my aging MacBook Pro but worked like a charm!